# Why my github repo not showing up in google search?

Tags: github, google-search

I have crated a repo in github named [Covid-19-Predictor-BD](https://github.com/abd-shoumik/Covid-19-Predictor-BD). I have also linked it up to **Github Pages** which you can see at
https://abd-shoumik.github.io/Covid-19-Predictor-BD/ 
But when I search 'Covid-19-Predictor-BD' or some related keyword in google , my repo doesn't appear in the search. What I can do to make the repo appear in google search??

Comment: Hilariously, this question is actually showing up higher in Google than your Github repo. One possibility would be to post your repo on something like Reddit or a personal blog so you get some back-links.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.